# Get objects from collection with Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have an object in C# which has a few properties:

```
// Pseudo class
public class
{
    Id;
    To;
    From;
}
```

I have alot instances of that class in a `Collection`. Which could look like this:

```
object 1:
  Id: 1
  To: "PathA"
  From: "PathB"

object 2:
  Id: 2
  To: "PathB"
  From: "PathC"

object 3:
  Id: 3
  To: "PathC"
  From: "PathA"
```

Now what I want to do is get all the items from that collections where the value of `To` doesn't appear in the `From` in any of the objects. Which would result in the following:

```
object 1:
  Id: 1
  To: "PathA"
  From: "PathB"

object 2:
  Id: 2
  To: "PathB"
  From: "PathC"
```

Because the last object with `Id: 3` has `PathA` in the `From` property, which already exists somewhere in the `To` property.

How can I do this with a Linq query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, how to go about this problem? First, you could create an index of all the values of `To`. Then, filter your sequence based on the `From` property...

Something like:

```
var tos = new HashSet<string>(collection.Select(item => item.To));
var filtered = collection.Where(item => !tos.Contains(item.From));
```

You might want to check, if creating a `HashSet` really works like this, or if you need to construct it differently... but you get the idea. Sets are efficient, if the `tos` gets rather long, since you will be checking this a lot...

Comment: `really works like this` - it does, one of `HashSet` constructors takes `IEnumerable<T>`, since Linq `Select` return `IEnumerable<T>`  this will compile and work. I also love MoreLINQ `ToHashSet()` extension method, you don't need to declare `<string>` generic parameter, all is inferred.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov :) nice. I like it, when a framework just works as expected!

Answer (score 1):

Say your collection of objects is as follows:

```
var objects = { object1, object2, object3 }
```

Then you want:

```
var result = objects.Where(o => !objects.Select(x => x.From).Contains(o.To));
```

If it concerns a large dataset, it might be smart to cache and store the sub-selection of "From" paths:

```
var fromPaths = new HashSet<string>(objects.Select(x => x.From));
var result = objects.Where(o => !fromPaths.Contains(o.To))
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your sample doesn't really match the question-text since all the sample objects have a `To` corresponding to some other `From`. But assuming the question-text is right and the sample is wrong:

How about with a [group-join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534297.aspx):

```
var query = from obj in collection
            join fromObj in collection
                 on obj.To equals fromObj.From
                 into objGroup
            where !objGroup.Any()
            select obj;
```

Alternatively, build up a set of distinct Froms first:

```
var distinctFroms = new HashSet<string>(collection.Select(item => item.From));

var query = from obj in collection
            where !distinctFroms.Contains(obj.To)
            select obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = collection.Select(c=>c.To).Distinct().ToList();
var result = collection.Where(c=>!list.Contains(c.From)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you join the collection back onto itself using To and From as the respective keys, you can establish which items are "joined" via To/From and exclude them:

```
var itemsThatAreConnected = 
    collection.Join(collection, x => x.To, x => x.From, (a,b) => a);
var unconnected = collection.Except(itemsThatAreConnected);
```